# CakePHP - Controller Delete Action does not receive Post Data

Tags: cakephp

I seem to have run into an issue in which my controller is not receiving the post data being sent to it via the postLink form helper.

I have multiple controllers, all of which seem to run OK with this action, however, this specific one will not.

I have attempted to debug, and have found that the Delete action does not seem to be receiving any Post data.

View postLink code:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('controller' => 'tokens', 'action' => 'delete', $data['token']['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete this data?'));
```

Controller code:

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);

    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
       throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
    }

    $this->Token->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Token->exists()) {
       throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid Token'));
    }

    if ($this->Token->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The token has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The token could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'accounts', 'action' => 'addToken'));
}
```

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong or what could be causing it, I've been racking my brain and testing different theories all day but nothing seems to change.  All componenets, helpers, etc. are loaded in the same manner the other controllers.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

(CakePHP Version 2.6.2)

**EDIT**
It looks like there is something going on with a session redirect, in which Cake is redirecting me to /accounts/users/sessionStatus.

I'm have no idea why this is happening.

**EDIT**
After further digging, I have noticed that when I enter the URl directly into the address bar, everything works as expected, however, clicking the link that was generated by the postLink method prevents the post data from being available.

I'm open to any suggestions/questions/help, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: @AD7six An opportunity to clarify myself if you don't think I was clear would be appreciated prior to a downvote.  As postLink is a helper function of CakePHP and I don't have the time to dig into this right now, I have no understanding of how it is being passed.  I was using my browser tools extensively, the form is "formed" correctly alongside the appropriate JS.  The receiving method shows the post var exists with isset.  When a zero is passed, there is no value inside the var, however any value > 0 registers as a value.

Comment: That is actually exactly how stackoverflow works.  Look up stackoverflow ettiquette.  It's extremely disappointing to find someone who seems to have so much experience with CakePHP and answers as many questions as you apparently have, belittle others instead of asking genuine questions to help the person get to the root cause. I obviously didn't understand what was happening at the time and was looking for help. I would suggest that in the future you approach people differently that may not know as much as you about a certain topic.

Comment: Also, as a CakePHP user with your level of experience, you should be familiar with postLink and the manner in which it operates from the code above.

Comment: Sorry but no, that is not [how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down), you can read more about voting [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740); [as a courtesy _to you_](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281604), I gave a comment why I voted on both posts here _to prompt you to edit them_. This hasn't happened and I'm sorry you have taken my actions as an ad-hominem attack. Good luck with your app/future questions.

Comment: Just saying something does not make it true.  I familiarized and refreshed myself with how stackoverflow worked years prior to my comment.  It is absolutely how it works.  I have edited my comments, you have lied.  Unfortunately I could edit them numerous times, but without direction I have no idea what you are looking for. In fact, your comments gave no specific direction, only critique which was not constructive at all.  I regularly welcome constructive criticism and still would.  It is also unfortunate that you have chosen to delete your comments.

Comment: You are the expert, if you choose to help, it is your responsibility to guide a student towards the information you need in order to help them solve a problem.
I hope in your future efforts, you seek to teach instead of use the power you have to belittle people.

Comment: Also, by your own definition, I clearly included examples of my code and the precise issue I was having.  If you can find others who agree my question was sloppy, I would concede.

Comment: The thing you need to understand is that the method you're asking about _doesn't generate any post data_. This is the root cause of whatever conflict you think exists between us. Look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxxtG.png) (note that _method is internal and basically irrelevant), read your question and then perhaps you'll understand why neither the question nor your answer makes any sense. If you actually want help, I can help you. If you just want to pretend that you're right and I'm wrong (or I have lied - er, wat?) - I'm not going to get in your way. Again, good luck </end>

Answer (score -1):

After 8 long hours, I finally determined the cause.

The javascript function handling the form is treating a zero (0) as a null so while the var exists and isset, no value is being passed.

If someone knows/understands more about this, please share!

Comment: This is what is generated by the helper method postLink `<form name="post_584ffb3f1c9b3359578158" style="display:none;" method="post" action="/some/url"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></form><a href="#" onclick="document.post_584ffb3f1c9b3359578158.submit(); event.returnValue = false; return false;">Delete</a>` - it does nothing but submit a form, with no data. This answer does not make any sense.